# Adjective for 'of a specific day'

Tags: adjectives

Is there a single-word adjective that means 'of a specific day'?

The contexts I'm thinking of are in the Catholic Church, where particular days are designated as commemorations of one or more saints.

> St Stephen is the _____ saint of the 26th of December.

An alternative context would be the feast day of a god in Classical times.

> Socrates wrote a hymn to an unknown god, the _____ god of the day his trial was delayed by.

'Daily' doesn't work, because it implies that the event is repeated every 24 hours (daily bread).

Comment: You could actually consider *specific* for both of those blanks.

Comment: You could and I think you should leave both those blanks out.

That December 26 is St Stephen's Day doesn't at all make St Stephen *the saint of 26 December*. 

If it did, why would it be different from *Stephen is the (patron) saint of* deacons, headaches, horses, coffin makers, and masons, often represented with rocks on his head?

Stephen’s feast day crops up in the carol Good King Wenceslas…

I suspect no-one would ever turn that round to say *the carol of Wenceslas* let alone *Wenceslas is the (blank) of that carol which bears his name*.

Comment: St Stephen is one of the saints commemorated on 26 December - http://www.catholic.org/saints/f_day/dec.php, and I could still do with an adjective to describe the link.

Comment: I think your examples are different. The Catholic "Saint's Day" is a day on which a particular saint is commemorated and venerated. It's a little like a person's birthday or "Bloom's Day" as celebrated by fans of James Joyce: it does not mean that that saint has special responsibility for that day. Socrates's unknown god, however would seem to be the _presiding spirit_ of the paticular day, in the same way as a water nymph might be the presiding spirit of a particular spring or a wood nymph the presiding spirit of a particular grove.

Comment: Saint Stephen is  commemorated on the 26th of December. Because St. Stephen is the saint can sound - though it may not technically be - redundant.

Answer (score 1):

How about [commemorated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commemorate)? It has no specific association with the *day/daily* aspect but it seems to fit with the religious recognition.

> 1 :to call to remembrance ·St. Andrew is commemorated on November 30.

Comment: Right, no St. X is the saint.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply say "December 26 is the feast day of St Stephen Protomartyr."  I assume good King Wenceslas would have looked out on the evening of the day after Christmas in the Christmas carol--though he might have been looking out on the evening of Christmas Day itself, that being the eve of St Stephen's feast day.  I don't know what the practice was in medieval times.  The Wenceslas actually referred to is Saint Wenceslaus I, Duke [not King] of Bohemia [Svatý Václav in Czech], who lived from 907 to 935.  There was a King Wenceslaus of Bohemia [Wenceslaus I Premyslid], who reigned more than three centuries later.  The modern Christmas carol was written by John Neale in 1853, and set to a 13th-century spring or Easter carol tune.